# Enable CORS for Docker Dev environment

Tags: angular, api, docker, identityserver4

What would be the best method of enabling CORS for my Docker Dev environment? My application runs fine locally, but my app's API cant pull database info onto the Angular Front-end once the user has logged in via Identity Server.

Would it make sense to use an nginx container to enable CORS across my app? There seems to be a fair amount of documentation on that.

The error message I keep receiving from the console when I run my app in Docker post-login is :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5004' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.